# Bundle not found in bnd-cache

Tags: osgi, bnd, bndtools

I have a problem with bndtools. The resolving is completed with no problems, but after I clicked on "Run OSGi" in a run descriptor following problem appears:

`Status ERROR: bndtools.core code=0 jena-arq~;version=[2.9.4,2.9.5) Not found in [bnd-cache, aQute.lib.deployer.obr.LocalOBR@1fef0b44, aQute.lib.deployer.obr.OBR@6ccadbd, aQute.lib.deployer.obr.LocalOBR@67a256c7, aQute.lib.deployer.obr.OBR@2d52912f] null`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at jena-arq~ you must list jena-arq twice in one of the lists ... bnd appends a name with a ~ if there is a duplicate. This should be remove of course before the name is sought, please file a bug about this. However, ensuring each name is only once in the list should work also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. OK, I checked it. The only thing is that I have two different versions of jena-arq in my obr repository. And booth were resolved.

Comment: Can you file a bug on github/bndtools/bnd for this? I guess bnd needs to remove the ~ at the end then since it could be required (though undesired) to have the same bundle twice.